# How to solve this error "The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

When i run my application I am getting the following error

> The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid

This is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection,   EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5">
     <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,    PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <!--  SqlCeConnectionFactory-->
      <parameters>
        <!--<parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />-->
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
 </entityFramework>
```

In this line I am getting an error

> public HQMEntities() : base("name=HQMEntities", "HQMEntities")

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWWV0.png)

Comment: You have missed to add a section with the connections strings. So your application can't find how to speak to your databases(s). You shouldn't add  here in your post :) on SO, with usernames, passwords, data soruce....! So try to add them and run your app again.

Comment: @Christos can you tell exactly where should i need to give the connections string?.. please. I am new to ado.net, thanks

Comment: of course, please have a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233(v=vs.85).aspx. You are welcome